# Wireless Router Username and Password Access

Tags: cisco, router, wifi

Does anyone know of a Wireless N Router that would allow me to setup Usernames and Passwords instead of an SSID and Password? The problem I am having is when my company lets an employee go I have to constantly change the wifi password and re-pass it out to current users.

Comment: You may use RADIUS for wifi authentication.

Comment: Okay and does Radius come with all wifi routers and if not can you point me in the right direction to find it?

Comment: [RADIUS is an acronym for Remote Authentication Dial User Service](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security-vpn/remote-authentication-dial-user-service-radius/12433-32.html)

Comment: Now is this Radius only available on Cisco routers and is that the terminology that I should look for when purchasing a router?

Comment: You could also combine an open or preshared ssid with a captive portal setup.

Comment: RADIUS is a protocol and is not Cisco-proprietary. If it's a "home" router you usually search for something like "WPA-Enterprise" and "802.1x".

Comment: Well this router is for work with about 30 employees. And like I said every time the let someone go I have to change the password for the ssid to block the fired user. I was just hoping that they would have a wireless router that you could enter user name and passwords vs ssid and password. So then I can add all the employees set a password for them and give them access. If they get fired then just simply remove them from the router and done!

Comment: RADIUS is a widely-used standard that's used by multiple vendors.  How exactly you can best implement it also depends on your server and client environments... so if you want proper advice, you should probably lay out your environment with as much detail as possible.  What router, specifically, do you have, what OSes do your clients use, what OSes do your servers use, what domain system (if any - Active Directory, Open Directory, generic LDAP, etc.) and so on.

Comment: `I was just hoping that they would have a wireless router that you could enter user name and passwords vs ssid and password.`  That sounds like more work than you'd like too.  Certainly more work than I'd be bothered with.  If you set up certificate-based WPA, you can control access via Active Directory (or other LDAP), for example.  So when someone gets fired, all you need to do is disable or delete their AD account, and they can't access wireless anymore.  You can also setup the environment to automagically connect to and configure the client for wireless, among other benefits.

Comment: But is Radius done over the router or is that a device in between the server and router? I'm reading How Does Radius work by Cisco now to try and make more sense.

Comment: RADIUS is a protocol.  The router authenticates against something (usually a server) to determine if the user and/or device in question should be allowed to access the network.  You can have a dedicated RADIUS server, add the role to an existing server, or even have local authentication on your network device(s).  Like I said, "the best" way (or the easiest way, or whatever else) depends on the specifics of your environment.

Comment: Well right now i have a Windows 2008 server and the user names are station 1, 2, etc... and the password for the workstations are station 1, 2, etc... How would I be able to successfully incorporate radius in to that if all the users know each workstations password? The company wanted it this way vs having there own username and password. Would radius work for something like this environment?

Comment: Well you can do it that way if you want and change the passwords when people leave but realistically, no, I don't think you'd be happy with RADIUS but that will be because of the dysfunctional nature of the network management here rather than any failing of RADIUS or the wireless access points, etc.

Comment: To use radius do you have to have active directory installed on the Windows 2008 server?

Comment: I was googleing radius and found this http://docs-legacy.fortinet.com/cb/html/index.html#page/FOS_Cookbook/Wireless/wireless-RADIUS.html Has anyone ever used this equipment before to do radius?

Answer (score 2):

As @BlueCompute pointed out you can use RADIUS authentication with your wifi.

This consists of 802.1x authentication to a RADIUS server in your network.
Most common wifi routers support this and it is commonly refered to as [WPA2-Enterprise](https://superuser.com/questions/726428/what-does-the-radius-server-do-in-a-wpa2-enterprise-setup).

You can check on your router if this option is present.

Comment: It's most likely not so I will be buying a new Wifi router but just want to make sure I understand how this works to make sure I get the right piece of equipment.